# Does TLS fallback only keep from downgrades to SSLv3?

Tags: tls, attacks, openssl, cipher-selection

I have read the RFC on this and can't seem to find what I am wanting to know. When implemented, if a client and a server support TLS fallback protection, does it only keep them from downgrading to SSLv3, or for example if the connection is made at TLS1.2, will it hold it there? Or will it allow it to fall back to 1.1 or 1.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The `TLS_FALLBACK_SCSV` draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-downgrade-scsv-03) protects against *any* downgrade attack. When a client's first handshake attempt fails and it falls back to a lower TLS version (including *but not limited to* SSL 3), it will include the SCSV, and the server can know that the client *wants* to support a higher version but was prevented from doing so. If the server also supports a higher version than the one the client fell back to, it will generate a fatal alert, since there should be no reason for the client to fall back *below* the server's highest-supported version.

Comment: Also one can just configure their clients to just not support older versions of TLS after all

Comment: To clarify client is browsers like Firefox chrome and etc

Comment: Since i can't edit my comments anymore lol... https://www.howsmyssl.com/ this site can be usefull to check your browser TLS configuration